# PSQLException: The column name "blah was not found in this ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I've been stuck on this bug for a while now, but I feel like I may just be making a minor error. I have tried erasing the class and rebuilding it, but to no avail. I have also tried deleting the table in PostgreSQL and re-building it, but it didn't work. When I switch the ResultSet positions in the connectlist it is always the second parameter that doesn't work. If there are any problems you can spot I would greatly appreciate it! By the way, this is Java. I am getting exception :         "**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name connect_name was not found in this ResultSet**." in the following code.

```
    String friendsSelect = "SELECT * FROM public.connect WHERE(username_='"+ loginUsername.toUpperCase() +"' OR connect_name='"+ loginUsername.toUpperCase() +"' AND complete_='YES');";

    connectList.add(new Connect(rs.getString("username_"),rs.getString("connect_name"),rs.getString("complete_"), rs.getString("date_"),rs.getString("username_image"),rs.getString("friendname_image"),rs.getString("online_user"), rs.getString("connect_online")));

    public class Connect {
    private String username;
    private String friendname;
    private String complete;
    private String datestring;
    private String user_image;
    private String friendImage;
    private String online;
    private String friend_online;


    public Connect(String username, String friendname, String complete, String datestring, String user_image, String friendImage, String online, String friend_online) {
        this.username = username;
        this.friendname = friendname;
        this.complete = complete;
        this.datestring = datestring;
        this.user_image = user_image;
        this.friendImage = friendImage;
        this.online = online;
        this.friend_online = friend_online;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFriendname() {
        return friendname;
    }

    public void setFriendname(String friendname) {
        this.friendname = friendname;
    }

    public String getComplete() {
        return complete;
    }

    public void setComplete(String complete) {
        this.complete = complete;
    }

    public String getDatestring() {
        return datestring;
    }

    public void setDatestring(String datestring) {
        this.datestring = datestring;
    }

    public String getUser_image() {
        return user_image;
    }

    public void setUser_image(String user_image) {
        this.user_image = user_image;
    }

    public String getFriendImage() {
        return friendImage;
    }

    public void setFriendImage(String friendImage) {
        this.friendImage = friendImage;
    }

    public String getOnline() {
        return online;
    }

    public void setOnline(String online) {
        this.online = online;
    }

    public String getFriend_online() {
        return friend_online;
    }

    public void setFriend_online(String friend_online) {
        this.friend_online = friend_online;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please correct your sql query...

Comment: Check here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/how-do-i-list-all-columns-for-a-specified-table for a guide to getting the names of columns in a table.